# How is this set called?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that $G$ has a number $\lambda$ of connected components.

let $\Omega\subset V$ be a set such that no connected component $W$ of $G$ is contained on the subgraph induced by $\Omega$. How is $\Omega$ called? I was in a hurry during a test and defined it as above and called it "non-saturator" but does it has an specific name?

Comment: So, for example, $\Omega = \varnothing$ would work, but not $\Omega = V$, and in general, $\Omega$ has to be missing at least one vertex from each connected component of $G$?

Comment: Exactly! Thats it.

Comment: I'm sorry, because I said that $\Omega$ misses at least one vertex  from each c.component I should call $\Omega$ "non-saturator". I'll correct it to make the notation a little less confusing.